# Endpoints API authentication with Google

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

I want to authenticate the request coming to my api such that its a valid google account.

```
@endpoints.api(name='echo', 
           version='v1',
           allowed_client_ids=[API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID,
                               "*****-************.apps.googleusercontent.com"],
           auth_level=AUTH_LEVEL.REQUIRED)
class EchoApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(
                    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
                    ECHO_RESOURCE,
                    # This method returns an Echo message.
                    EchoResponse,
                    path='echo',
                    http_method='POST',
                    name='echo',
                    api_key_required=True)
    def echo(self, request):
        print endpoints.get_current_user()
        print request
        output_content = ' '.join([request.content] * request.n)
        return EchoResponse(content=output_content)
```

Above is the code that i implemented then also if i send a request without authorization header the request still reaches backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check if get_current_user() returns None.

auth_level does not actually do anything in this version of the Framework.